Facing Error while importing .bacpac file in D365 F&O CHE
While trying to import a database backup .bacpac file in the newly created CHE, I get an error :

Error SQL72014:core Microsoft sqlclient Data provider:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AIFSqlRowversionINVENTJOURNALHISTORYAfterDelete, Line9
Invalid column name 'SYSDATASTATE'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
CREATE TRIGGER AIFSqlRowversionINVENTJOURNALTABLEHISTORYAfterDelete
ON dbo.INVENTJOURNALTABLEHISTORY
AFTER DELETE
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO AIFCHANGETRACKINGDELETEOBJECT (CHANGEDTABLEID, CHANGEDTABLERECID, DELETETIME, ISARCHIVALDELETE)
SELECT 28129,
RECID,
GETUTCDATE(),
SYSDATASTATE
FROM   DELETED,
END

We tried

FULL BUILD
DB SYNC

Still the error persists.
